# Which math classes should be included in an undergraduate computer science program?

Tags: undergraduate-education, curriculum, computer-science

As part of my job search, I've come into contact with universities that are beginning to offer new majors at their university such as applied mathematics or computer science. A frequent interview question is, "What kind of classes would you require for such a major?"

I usually tell them that I would look at other universities that have established programs and try to use them as a template, together with my own experience. However, I was wondering:

> Is there any published research, news articles, or other reliable sources which indicate which mathematical skills are most important/most used in typical computer programmer positions in industry?

While I appreciate colloquial advice, I am specifically looking for published information.

Comment: I'm not in computer science nor know too much about the modern needs of some of its subfields, but if I had to venture a guess: Discrete (Intro to proofs and logic), Linear Algebra, and perhaps Numerical Analysis for the basics and perhaps recommended Abstract Algebra (group and ring theory) for the more advanced/specialized majors. I know some PhD CS students here (large US university) also take some Analysis and Probability courses.

Comment: Just one further thought. Is this aimed at potential students going on to a PhD, Industry, or potentially both?

Comment: @ChrisC Industry. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Any CS major should have come into school already knowing discrete math, calculus, and stats.  Therefore they should only need to take abstract algebra, analysis, and probability courses for a sufficient education.

Comment: Late comment: Depends on the level of the school. For example, I can confidently state that 0% of the CS majors at our community college have any of the "come into school already knowing" requirements stipulated by alternative's comment above. Each of those is a terminal course for our 2-year degree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two references might help. Neither is aimed at industry needs specifically, but
undergraduate computer science curricula are partially driven
by industry job market needs. The first is aimed specifically at liberal arts colleges:

> (1) "A 2007 Model Curriculum for a Liberal Arts Degree
>   in Computer Science,"
>   *Liberal Arts Computer Science Consortium*, 2007.
>   ([PDF download link](http://cs.wellesley.edu/~pmetaxas/LACS2007report.pdf).)

Here is an excerpt; more detail in the report:

---

[image: ACM07]

---

The second is more recent, and not specific to liberal arts colleges
(but agrees with the above):

> (2) "Computer Science
>   Curricula 2013:
>   Curriculum Guidelines for
>   Undergraduate Degree Programs
>   in Computer Science." 2013. ([PDF download link](http://www.acm.org/education/CS2013-final-report.pdf).)

Here is a snippet (p.467) of topics coverage, all of which are required
at "Tier-1" universities:

---

[image: ACMTopics]

---